# How does the actuator render its endpoints?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Good morning all,

Hopefully this is a really simple question.

How are spring-boot-actuator endpoints supported?

I can see the @ReadOperation and @WriteOperation for most of them, but I don't see where the base URL is supported or what technologies support the creation of the 'http://localhost:8080/actuator' endpoint.

My project does show the JSON (I guess that's what that is?) when I navigate to the address 'http://localhost:8080/actuator' instead of showing a 404 or 500.

I would like to understand the underlying architecture of the spring-boot-actuator project.  The 'http://localhost:8080/actuator' URL is active, returns, and shows data.

This URL does not seem to be annotated with:

```
@ResponseBody
```

```
@RequestMapping
```

```
@GetMapping
```

```
@ReadOperation
```

The 'http://localhost:8080/actuator' doesn't seem to be supported in the micrometer project.

I'm very confused as to how the actuator programming works.

Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root actuator endpoint *(default: /actuator)* which you are referring to, is indeed annotated with `@ResponseBody`. You can check it out here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/0a4c26532dff6f3fa1bf6d2e1c2a74549191117a/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/web/servlet/WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.java#L76